# iOS 8 Navigation Bar Not Accessible in Second ViewController on Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am new to iOS development and have not tried this programmatically yet. I would prefer to get this working in a storyboard.

I'm following this somewhat outdated tutorial from XCode 4.5 in XCode 6.1 to create a series of views connected by one navigation controller.
http://youtu.be/rgd6mCuzlEc

[image: Screenshot]

Once I create the second view controller, I am unable to double click the navigation bar to change the name and I am unable to add a bar button to it.

I have a Segue going from bar button "Item" from view 1 to 2. Notice in the "View Controller Scene" there is no navigation item. If I add any elements to the view controller they fall under "View" and not under "View Controller", unlike view controller 1 where it falls under "one".

Is this a limitation on XCode? Am I using the wrong Segue (Show)? Is there a hidden setting or customization I'm missing?

I actually have this working for 2 view controllers and failing the 3rd in a separate project but I don't know what I did to do that so I'm pretty sure it's possible I just cannot reproduce..

**EDIT:** *Workaround* Instead of the new adaptive SHOW segue, use the deprecated PUSH segue, add the bar button items, then change back to the adaptive SHOW segue.

Comment: is there a way to make it work with the new SHOW segue?

Comment: Workaround you mentioned works well. Hope it will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try adding a Navigation Item to the controller and it should work properly

[image]

Comment: I also found a workaround that seems to automatically add the item for you but this is the correct answer. Thank you!

Comment: Just to add to this solution, I didn't have to link the navigationItem to the class at all. I just dragged and dropped into into the UIViewController and linked a barbuttonItem I needed. Even changing the navigationItem's title works programatically without linking.

Comment: @DanielE:  Glad I found this comment!! However it begs the question of why it needs to be done this way?  Is there a correct way of doing this?

Comment: Perfect Thanks :)

Comment: You have no idea how long it took me to find this. THANK YOU!